# Custom editor window - (Texture2D)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField Doesnt display or open an image when selected or dropped in

Tags: unity-game-engine

OK, I remember having this issue in the past, but I can't figure it out now. This is my code

tex = (Texture2D)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Sand", tex, typeof(Texture2D), false);

Where tex is a texture2d declared and initialized as null. If I initialize it with a texture, the

texture shows but I can't select or drop one in to get the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I asked AI in Bing and no matter what, it always gives me the same results which are all correct on my end. It finally gave up and said I should ask you. No, really. LOL Searching the web by myself is useless.

I have no answer to this I tried everything to no avail. The code I believe is correct.

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out. I was declaring the variable in GUI instead of outside of a function etc. Once I did that, all is well. If anyone else has this issue, just make sure to declare your variable at the top of the file as you would normally. Fixed.

Comment: That solution doesn't really make sense ... Maybe you should share your context code .. otherwise it is hard to tell what it going on exactly

Comment: Sorry it is really simple. I was declaring my variable inside of ONGUI which constantly reset it to null. Just making it a public variable instead fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using `Serializedobject.`

Step 1. **convert object to Serializedobject** (Perform on Initialization and save reference)

`var tex_so = new Serializedobject(PARENT OF tex);`

Step 2. **show in editor window** (Perform on every GUI update)

`EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(tex_so.FindProperty("tex"));`

Step 3. **Apply changes** (Perform on every GUI update)

`tex_so.ApplyModifiedProperties();`